# concat char* with char netbea

Tags: c, string, char

I need to concatenate a string with a char in c but I not figured it out. This is part of my code:

```
  unsigned char c ='d';
  char *respuesta;

   while(ciclo)
    {
        nanosleep((struct timespec[]){{0, INTERVAL_MS}}, NULL);
        //veces++;

       if (read(tty_fd,&c,1)>0)
       {
         write(STDOUT_FILENO,&c,1);
         respuesta = append(respuesta,c); 
       }
       else{ciclo = false;}
    }

    void append(char* s, char *c)
    {
        int len = strlen(s);
        s[len] = c; // in this line I got the error.
        s[len+1] = '\0';
    }
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
void append(char* s, char *c)
```

to:

```
void append(char* s, char c)
```

since you want to append a `char` (single character) to a `char *` (string).

Also make sure that you have allocated (sufficient) memory to `respuesta` - it's just a wild pointer in the code above, but hopefully you have actually `malloc`d a suitable amount of storage.